# Overloading operator<< and operator!=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i have problem with operators overloading in c++. 
I have struct which represents Complex numbers and i am overloading operators, so i can do calculations with complex numbers.
Visual Studio 2012 gives me this error:
1 IntelliSense: no operator "!=" matches these operands
operand types are: std::ostream != Complex

my != function code

```
bool operator!=(const Complex& lhs, const Complex& rhs)
{
    if( lhs.Real() != rhs.Real() || lhs.Imaginary() != rhs.Imaginary() )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

<< code

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream,  const Complex& number)
{
    stream << number.Real() << "+" << number.Imaginary() << "i" << endl;

    return stream;
}
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    Complex c1(1,5),c2(5,6);

    cout << c1 != c2;

    system("pause"); 

    return 0;
}
```

if i do this though

```
cout << (c1 != c2);
```

it gives me no errors.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem without the need to add parentheses?

Comment: no, that's how the order of operations work in c++. It's like asking how you can get `4 + 5 * 6` to do the addition before the multiplication - not possible.

Comment: And what's with this `if (condition) return true; else return false;`?  Why not the simpler and less verbose `return condition;`.

Comment: Why the ìf`in the implementation of `operator!=()`? Just return `lhs.Real() != rhs.Real() || lhs.Imaginary() != rhs.Imaginary()`

Comment: You can use a separate statement and store the result of the operation in another variable, then use `cout` to print that variable. But I don't see why you wouldn't want to just use parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your error occurs with

```
cout << c1 != c2
```

it's a precedence issue.  it's being parsed as

```
(cout << c1) != c2
```

if you really can't stand the look of the extra parens. you could do

```
cout << operator!=(c1, c2);
```

but I expect you don't care much for the look of that either